# Pixijs 7 load texture via Asset background loading

Tags: javascript, textures, assets, pixi.js

I am getting stuck on loading a texture via pixi 7 new Asset package. What I want to do is loading the ressource (png file) via asset loader. Then create a TilingSprite with the loaded ressource as texture. The following code will never finish:

```
  const textureFromAsset = PIXI.Texture.from(assets.tiles);
  const gridFromAsset = new PIXI.TilingSprite(textureFromAsset, 250, 250);
  app.stage.addChild(gridFromAsset);
```

The ressource is loaded and shown correctly by using a Sprite. How can I load textures via pixi asset loader?

A full codepen example is [here](https://codepen.io/stot/pen/bGQWzeJ?editors=0011)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qick Solution: There is no need to create an extra texture. The asset can go as texture:

> const gridFromAsset = new PIXI.TilingSprite(assets.tiles, 250, 250);